# Excel: How do I find the highest sum for both columns D and E, if my limit for F is 5000?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I have attached a link to the image of my spreadsheet!

This is a list of influencers, I have a 5000 budget for Column F, and id like to assemble a group of any number of influencers, having the groups sum for column F not exceed 5000, and with the group having the highest possible sum for engagement rate (column D) andtotal viewership (column E)

In other words, I'm wondering if a function or formula can take every possible combination of influencers that I could afford for 5000, and find the group with the highest total viewership and engagement

- I created the pricing at a rate of $0.02 per view

Comment: Please tell us more on your problem.

Comment: D is always smaller than E from your image. Please provide more detail as to what you are trying to do

Comment: I added this to the description: This is a list of influencers, I have a 5000 budget for Column F, and id like to assemble a group of any number of influencers, having the groups sum for column F not exceed 5000, and with the group having the highest possible sum for engagement rate (column D) andtotal viewership (column E)

Comment: hopefully that makes sense

Comment: So what did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: Try some of your own work and tell us where you get stuck, at which point you can be helped. Nobody is going to write "free code" for you

Comment: what I did was 1) order the influencers in decreasing number of viewers 2) take the top viewed influencers that I could afford w 5000, which got me about 5 influencers 3) ordered the influencers in decreasing number of engagement 4) take the top engaging influencers that I could afford w 5000 5) compared the two groups, and found that taking the top engaging influencers I could afford gave me higher a higher sum of viewership and engagement

Comment: but I'm wondering if a function can take every possible combination of influencers that I could afford for 5000, and find the group with the highest total viewership and engagement

Comment: I would think the best way would be to create a column that represents the #viewers/$dollars. Then you can find which ones make the best bang for your buck until it reaches $5000. Would this meet what you are looking for?

Comment: Please edit your quesiton and show it in the original post. This will help other people (Remember, this is a Q and A site, not a forum) to see the issue without having to read all the comments etc

Comment: I actually created the pricing myself, at a rate of $0.02 per view

Comment: Column F looks like E * .02, so E is implicit. Ignore E.

Comment: ohh @Yorik I see, because if I'm spending 5000, ill total the same amount of viewers either way! wow

Comment: Still, to "bucket" them most effectively I would thing a rating/$ column would be most effective based on how you stated you are manually doing it

Comment: what happens if you sort by viewers and then rate and then took the median progressively until you ran out of money?

Comment: actually I think I found a simple solution...sort by view/rate, and then buy as many of the cheapest as I can! (starting from the bottom, buying up as much as I can) it seems to get me the highest possible engagement rate

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I found a simple solution...

- Sort by view/rate,
- and then buy as many of the cheapest as I can! (starting from the bottom, buying up as much as I can)
  It seems to get me the highest possible engagement rate